# flip image on mouseover based on direction

Tags: javascript, image, animation, onclick

Is there a way to make this script switch images based on the direction the pointer is?

For example, if you have a fish, and you move the mouse to the right of the fish, it switches to an image facing that way. When you move your pointer to the left of the fish, it points it the other way.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vhDpG/)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
$("#foo").mousemove(function(event) {
    $("#bee1").stop().animate({left: event.pageX, top: event.pageY}, 300)
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="foo">
<div id="bee1">MoveMe</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#foo{
  height:500px;
  width:400px;
}
#bee1{
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I recommend to save the `$('#bee1')` element in a global variable. You don't want JavaScript to search in the dom for that particular element each time you move your mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#foo").mousemove(function(event) {
        var bee = $("#bee1");
        var position = bee.position();
        var mousey = event.pageX;


    if(position.left > mousey) {
        $("#bee1").html("left");
    } else {
        $("#bee1").html("right");
    }

        $("#bee1").stop().animate({left: event.pageX, top: event.pageY}, 300);
});
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you so much. I replaced "left" and "right" with image codes and it's doing what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if current mouse position x is greater than image position and change your image `src` accordingly:

```
$("#foo").mousemove(function(event) {
    var mousePos = {x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY},
        elPos = imgEl.offset();
    if(mousePos.x > elPos.left){
        direction = '-->';
    }
    else{
        direction = '<--';
    }
    imgEl.text(direction);
    imgEl.stop().animate({left: event.pageX, top: event.pageY}, 300)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WfQwZ/